# Using the special Dual table to read sequences

Tags: oracle, sequence

It there a performance impact when using the dual table to read a sequence' nextval over an direct insert?

I'm currently optimizing the performance in a large IT system and what I've found is that almost all sequence.nextval are read in the following way:

```
SELECT SOME_SQ.NEXTVAL INTO someID FROM DUAL;
insert into .... (someId)
```

I'm wondering whether the performance might suffer when using the way as described above over a standard:

```
insert into .... (some_sq.nexval, ...)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that 11g has [support for sequence expressions directly in PL/SQL](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=507#9bc3a)

Otherwise, from [the Oracle Docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17118/queries009.htm#SQLRF20036):

> Beginning with Oracle Database 10g Release 1, logical I/O is not
>   performed on the DUAL table when computing an expression that does not
>   include the DUMMY column. This optimization is listed as FAST DUAL in
>   the execution plan.

So any performance gain will be slight. In the following tests I dropped and recreated the table and sequence between each execution:

testbed:

```
create sequence s;
create table t(id integer);
```

tests:

```
declare
  n integer;
begin
  for i in 1..100000 loop
    select s.nextval into n from dual;
    insert into t(id) values(n);
  end loop;
end;
/
--average about 5s

declare
  n integer;
begin
  for i in 1..100000 loop
    insert into t(id) values(s.nextval) returning id into n;
  end loop;
end;
/
--average about 4s

begin
  for i in 1..100000 loop
    insert into t(id) values(s.nextval);
  end loop;
end;
/
--average about 3s
```

You should probably rerun these tests or ones like them in you own environment.